# Javascript conflict three times

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript for a part of my website.

```
var fare = Math.round(fare*100)/100;
if(document.getElementById("doubleFare").checked)
{
   fare = fare * 2;
}
```

But when I use this 3 times at the script, one of the three will not work.

The other 2 times I use + insted of an *.

Who can help me to solve it? thanks

Comment: which parts is failing and how do you determine failure? How are you calling it the other two times? are you redefining `fare` with var everytime (note you shouldn't be)? In the example above you need to define fare as some value before using it in the assignment.

Comment: Nothing in your question indicates any solvable problem. Please post a representation of the issue you're having, as well as a description of what "will not work" means.

Comment: are you defining fare before you use it? var fare = Math.round(fare*100)/100; will just return NaN. Once it is defined, you can refrain from redefining it with var unless you intend to re-scope in another function which imho is bad form.

Comment: I am using two checkboxes for the script. One is the code that doubles the fare price. And one checkbox will add extra price to the total fare. But I can't use them together. The output only shows the total price without the checkboxes. When I delete one of the code it work fine..

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that shows what you're trying to do? There isn't enough information here to tell what's going on.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bUMRA/

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that you are constantly redefining variables and in some cases killing the intended scope. Once you `var` a variable don't do it again. For instance you have:

```
 if (total<40)
 {
     var cost = parseInt(total) * 1.95;
 }
  else
 {
    var cost = parseInt(total) * 1.65;
 }
 var fare = cost;
```

The issue here is you are redefining cost so it has a scope of inside the if/else block. Then when you are assigning `cost` to `fare` you are actually just setting `fare` to undefined since it can't be seen outside of the if block. Try:

```
/* code to get check box that indicates prices for 1.50 and 1.60 */
    var check150 = document.getElementById("yourCheckIdFor150").checked ? true : false;
    var check160 = document.getElementById("yourCheckIdFor160").checked ? true : false;
    var cost = parseInt(total) * 1.65;
    if(total < 40 && !check150 && !check160)
    {
        cost = parseInt(total) * 1.95;
    }else if(check150 && !check160)
    {
        cost = parseInt(total) * 1.50;
    }else if(!check150 && check160)
    {
        cost = parseInt(total) * 1.60;
    }

    var fare = cost;    
    fare = Math.round(fare*100)/100;
    if(document.getElementById("doubleFare").checked)
    {
        fare = fare * 2;
    }
```

If you want to show the price at the various values then you will need to use separate variables for the fares and initial cost and break the `else if` block apart into just `if(check160)` etc. If it only displays one option at a time the above will work.

Comment: Thank you. but I want also to add an if(total < 40) under doublefare with other prices. How to do this?

Comment: what do you mean with other prices?

Comment: now it is standard with *1.65 under 40 and *1.95 above 40. Thats okay, but I want to add another checkbox with two other: *1.50 and *1.60. so when checked the other prices will shown

Comment: i added a check for the possible checkboxs in my answer and gave a note as to what to do if you want to display them all.

Comment: thanks for it but what i want is 4 different prices for the calculator. when people click on checkbox 1 it has to be 2 prices. and when they click on checkbox 2, 2 other prices. and 1 price is above 40 and other below 40.

Comment: Then split the if-else to just if blocks and have a variable for each price you want to show, rather than reusing the same for each.

Comment: if you are using new variables (not using the same variable over and over again. actually going var price16; var price17;... how what isn't working?

Comment: Try breaking up each calculation you want to do into a separate function. Then all you have to do is return the value from these functions. That should take some of the confusion in the code out and you can really see where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this evening a lot of things, but no results. The double fare works fine. What I exactly try to do is; I have a checkbox for normal fare and a checkbox for a special fare. The normal fare costs **1.65 under 40km and 1.50 above 40km**. The special fare costs **1.95 under 40km and 1.75 above 40km**. So in total 4 different price ranges. I puzzled much but did not work... please can you help @scrappedcola